# Writing this complicated copy costructor without using std::copy function

Tags: c++

Please explain how to write the copy constructor for this class without using the `std::copy` functions.

```
class A {
    public:
        struct B {
            int aaprikhat;
            B* bajja;
        }
        A() : x(0) {}
        A(const A&)
    private:
        B* bajookha;    
}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
A::A(const A& a) {
    this->bajookha = new B();
    this->bajookha->aaprikhat = a.bajookha->aaprikhat;
    this->bajookha->bajja = a.bajookha->bajja; // I think this is wrong
    //I even tried doing this:
    //this->bajookha->bajja = new B();
    // But how to copy data from a.bajookha->bajja to this->bajookha->bajja?
}
```

As you can see, I'm badly stuck in a recursive thing of sorts. :(

Comment: We cannot know how this should work without knowing how your class should be copied. Is B a linked list node?

Comment: also, `std::copy` has nothing to do with writing copy constructors (well, may use copy constructors, but that's other another story)

Comment: use `std::forward_list<int>` instead of `B`, problem solved

Comment: Yes, technically, it's  a linked list node. How it is copied? You know, like passing it as an argument to a function.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Please!!! No modifications to the class please.

Comment: The features like copy and forward_list are discouraging to beginners.

Comment: You're going to need a copy-assignment operator, so you will have to modify the class. Also `B` should have a copy-constructor.

Comment: The features like copy and forward_list allow beginners and experts to write code faster which contains less bugs and is easier to understand. This C-style linked list and manual copy constructor is rubbish only taught in schools and has no place in real industrial C++. I know it is not your fault.

Comment: @TrentBoult That seems rather backwards. I would assume the more straight forward and less error prone approach would be more encouraging to beginners.

Comment: eh? How is one line of code `std::forward_list<int> bajookha;` more discouraging than writing dozens of lines of code which is difficult enough that you have to post on SO about it? (and no doubt spend hours debugging and perfecting)

Comment: @NeilKirk: They don't teach us those in class. I'm forced to do it the conventional way. :(

Comment: @MattMcNabb: You are right. I am wrong. You win. Now can someone please explain how to write the copy constructor in the conventional way, even though it's outdated? You can see my attempt and the dilemma I'm facing now.

Comment: Find a reference implementation of a linked list class and take the logic from its copy constructor.

Comment: @NeilKirk: That solution will use copy function again. :(

Comment: @TrentBoult "the 1990s way" would be a better description than "conventional". Anyway, give `B` a copy-constructor. Then `A`'s copy-constructor will have `this->bajookha = new B(*a.bajhooka);` . Currently you are trying to put code that should be in B's copy-constructor into A's.

Comment: You can find an implementation that doesn't use it.

Comment: Can you provide any link where I can read about the new way (how std:: copy works)?

Comment: So what all do I need to learn to use the latest method?

Comment: I don't see how `std::copy` is relevant to this example. To learn how to use standard containers such as `list` or `forward_list` read a book or some documentation. There's not great online documentation that I'm aware of but you can try [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) or look through other SO questions where people used `list`.  (`list` is slightly simpler than `forward_list`).

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of the copy constructor should be to create a new identical object that doesn't share any resources with the original. The implementation should go like this:

```
class A {
public:
    struct B {
        int aaprikhat;
        B* bajja;

        B() : aaprikhat(0), bajja(nullptr) {}
        B(B& obj) : aaprikhat(obj.aaprikhat) {
            if (obj.bajja != nullptr)
                bajja = new B(*obj.bajja);
            else
                bajja = nullptr;
        }
    };

    A() : x(0), bajookha(nullptr) {}
    A(const A& obj) : x(obj.x) {
        if (obj.bajookha != nullptr)
            bajookha = new B(*obj.bajookha);
        else
            bajookha = nullptr;
    }

private:
    B* bajookha;
    int x;
};
```

I guess that this is some kind of exercise to learn about c++ copy constructor. This example solves your problem but it's low level code and you should avoid it specially if there is something implemented in the standard library that might solve your problem.

PD: You should also implement a copy assignment operator. Thanks to [Matt McNabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) for the remainder.

Comment: Why have you not initialized `bajookha` in the constructor?

Comment: @TrentBoult Do you mean A's constructor? Initialization occurs inside the `if else` statement. Maybe you mean the default constructor of A. Sorry I fixed it.